# VBA - what element could it be after "!"

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am working on a excel file and met a problem with the chart. As the file is passed on to me, I opened the axis label of chart to see how the chart is made of. And I see the axis label is 'file.xlsm'!company_list, the weirdest thing is that the file does not have any sheet called company_list. I checked the VBA code of the file, there is no such a variable called company_list either.

I am wondering what element could be behind "!" without showing any trace in the file?

Comment: have a look at the name manager in the tab FORMULAS

Comment: THX Mate!  It really works!